# Automatically reformatting inherited PHP spaghetti code

Tags: php, code-formatting

I've taken over a mixed PHP4/PHP5 project which has been handed down from developer to developer, with each one making things worse. Before I spend too much time on it I'd like to develop a base-standard, with consistent formatting at a minimum.

Can anyone recommend a utility (Linux or Mac OS X preferably) that will reformat the code?

If I can set parameters which influence output (like tab-indentation, brace/bracket placement, when to split array values onto new lines etc.) then that's a benefit, though not crucial.

Preference goes to Open Source tools, though I'd like to know your experiences with purchased software too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do that with [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org) or with [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/), both excellent PHP editors.  There's a Format Code option in each, which will reformat a selected file according to your code style preferences.  There may be an option to format code in bulk as well.

I do recommend that if you do this, do the format and immediately check the code back in with a big fat "REFORMATTING!" comment.  Trying to mix in other bug fixes with the reformat makes for nasty-looking diff files to try to decipher down the road.

Comment: You can bulk format with Netbeans. Just highlight the files on the side panel and click Source > Format.

Answer (score 5):

I use phptidy: <s>http://cmr.cx/phptidy/</s> https://github.com/cmrcx/phptidy

By design, it's not as aggressive as perltidy, but it's still very useful. It can be configured and will do all the php files in your project as a batch.

Update: for a more aggressive, standards-based tool, consider PHP CS Fixer: https://github.com/FriendsOfPhp/PHP-CS-Fixer

Answer (score 2):

I've used http://www.phpformatter.com/, which is an online tool.

Answer (score 1):

Something I found recently, which I now love and use all the time. In vim:

```
gg=G
```

This requires the following configuration option, which you can set in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer). I have also used this [script](http://pastebin.com/f19c5df99)

Answer (score 0):

In my own searching I found [the Wikipedia article on Pretty Print](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prettyprint) which I think will be useful.